# Sherlock Library is showing error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock Library and for that I have download the library and used it as mentioned at this link http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html.

I have added the library code into Eclipse. Then I have created new Android Project named SharelockFragmentDemo and try to add the SherlockLibrary as follows,

> [image]

It shows that library is added successfully,

[image]

But after clicking the OK button when I open this dialog again then it shows me import error as follows,

[image]

Am I missing something while importing the library ? Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Remove it from the library and add again.

Comment: I tried that many times, also I clean both and restarted eclipse too, but result is 0.

Comment: Try putting the library folder in the same location as your project. It may work.

Comment: can you check the ABS library that you imported is showing as a library ? Also, I know you said you followed the instructions but it would be better if you could actually tell us what you did. Cheers.

Comment: Just place your lib project and android project in same directory.. I also experienced that..

Comment: @sandeep, Yes you are right, can you post your comment as answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the library folder in the same location as your project. It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your library and project into same drive and then import library from that drive and add it into your project

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.